# how to subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row in Html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm struggling with a PHP Code, and I have no clue how to solve this. I have two columns with timestamps on which I've ordered by desc in my Html table which I'm generating with PHP code.

Also, let me clear this up It's not about calculating time diff the Q. is how to subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row

I need to find out the differences between the 2nd row StateEndTime and the 1st-row StateStarTtime nd so on and display this in a new row/column. The final table should look like this :

```
ID          Type         StateStarTtime    StateEndTime   Min Difference

xxx         YYY          03:57             03:59          00:02
xxx         ZZZ          03:53             03:55          00:04
xxx         ZZZ          03:46             03:49
```

Below is the PHP code in my index file

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
  <tr>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
      <?php endwhile;?>
```

I need to perform the calculation in PHP. I only have the view access of the database I'm using below query to fetch the data `"SELECT * FROM time WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= Timestamp AND EmpID='".$valueToSearch."' ORDER BY time.Timestamp DESC"`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd

Comment: It's not about calculating time diff the Q. is how to subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer this is so simple because there is an example. You have to store both dates in the variable like this.and have to use this simple function because to make the date according to PHP.

```
$firstdate = date_create(echo $row['StateStarttime']);
```

and second date as well

```
$seconddate = date_create(echo $row['StateEndtime']);
```

and then you have to use this function as to make difference between both of them.

```
$diff=date_diff($firstdate,$seconddate);
```

and then you have to echo this diff variable as a product in 3rd column.

```
echo $diff;
```

> Here you go. If it helps then notice me by voting up and check the green tick.Thanks

Comment: It's not about calculating time diff the Q. is how to subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row

Comment: But he or she wants to make the difference between the times his or her question was wrong.

Comment: Q. itself state "how to subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row in Html table"